# Dynamics CRM 2011 creating relationships between custom entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have defined 3 entities in MSCRM 2011.

**1-Place**: This is the main entity. In this form I have some fields (let say IDs, Whole Number) that I want to create some relationships with other custom entities.
**2-Category**: This has two fields, ID(Whole number) and Category Name(text.) This is simply a relation entitiy.
**3-Place-Category Relationship**: This entity contains relationships between Category and Place. It has two main arguments, both of them are whole number.

One place can have more than one Category.

I want to display end user Place and the categories related to to that place entity.

Thanks in advance.

---

More info about this question:
- In *Place* entity each Place has a unique ID (1 = Train Station, 2 = Jhon's Kebab House, 3 = Nando's, 4 = Wagamama ...)
- In *Place* entity I have plenty of data but Category IDs are used to match places with categories (like 42, 108 etc.)
- In *Category* entity I have two fields. Category ID's matched with their category names (1 = Cafe, 2 = Restaurant ... 42 = Train Station, ... 108 = Grocery etc.)
- In *Place-Category Relationship* entity I have IDs of the places and the IDs for the cateories.(like PlaceID = 1 CategoryID =42, PlaceID = 2 CategoryID = 2, PlaceID = 2 CategoryID = 5 ..etc)

There are 140K Places, 200 Categories and more than 400K Place-Category Relationship.

One place has at least one, maximum 80 categories.

I want to match all my Places with their Categories entity (by aid of *Place-Category Relationship* entity).

I want to automate this matching process.

Comment: Hello again, I have created 1:N relationship between _Place_ and _Place-Category Relationship_ entities and N:N between _Place-Category Relationship_ and _Category_.  
I have manually matched these but I am confused with how to automate this process. Afaik workflows are not useful between entities.  
Anyone with an idea?

Comment: Would need a little more info to help here. What you're trying to achieve here is a little confusing. Firstly, I don't get what you need Place-Category for. Secondly, I think I know what you want to display in regard to "End user place and related categories", but this third entity is again confusing me. Maybe provide some sample data and the outputs you are looking for. Finally, what exactly are you trying to automate? Rather than adding a comment why not update your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

since you have said the each place can have many categories but not vice versa  .

so you just need two entities (Place,category) and you should create a one to many

relationship between them.

1. open the default solution
2. Expand  the place category
3. click on the 1:N relationship and create a relationship between it
   and the category entity

Note: to open the "default solution"  lick settings=> customizations => click customize the

system on the right